# How can I get the raw query sent from Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When I use kibana to search logs, the response time is very slow. How can I grab the raw query sent to Elasitcsearch from Kibana? I'd like to analyse why the query is very slow and how to improve that.

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000099/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the raw query, response time, request time etc. from the "inspect" option - in the visualizations or the discover page of Kibana.
[image: Inspect in Kibana]